# Woocommerce product quantity name, how can i change what is displayed?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've installed a plugin for my woocommerce's products which allow me to add prederminated quantity on a product, suddenly, in the front-end it's displayed "1400 items @$0.014 $20".
I've tried to change some parameters on the main php file, but i'm not sure i'm doing it right.

This part of php code come from the main folder of the plugin

```
if (!defined('ABSPATH'))
exit;
if (!in_array('woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters('active_plugins', get_option('active_plugins'))))
return;

if (!class_exists('WooFixedQuantity')) {

define("WOOFIXCONF_QTY_DESC", "{qty} items @{price} {total}");
define("WOOFIXCONF_SHOW_DISC", "yes");
define("WOOFIXCONF_SHOW_STOCK", "yes");
define("WOOFIXCONF_CHECK_STOCK", "no");
define("WOOFIXCONF_DEFAULT_ROLE", "customer");

define("WOOFIXOPT_QTY_DESC", "woofix_qty_desc");
define("WOOFIXOPT_SHOW_DISC", "woofix_show_disc");
define("WOOFIXOPT_SHOW_STOCK", "woofix_show_stock");
define("WOOFIXOPT_CHECK_STOCK", "woofix_check_stock");
define("WOOFIXOPT_DEFAULT_ROLE", "woofix_default_role");
define("WOOFIXOPT_AVAILABLE_ROLES", "woofix_available_roles");


class WooFixedQuantity
{
```

So i thought it was good to change this line of code

```
define("WOOFIXCONF_QTY_DESC", "{qty} items @{price} {total}");
```

but nothing happen, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: On the frontend *where*? In the cart? The product page? Checkout page?

Comment: Everywhere on the frontend, as now show "items"